# Removing Python venv from OneDrive

Tags: python, onedrive, python-venv

I did something stupid. I stored python project on OneDrive (yes with virtual environment set up). I don't have to mention how it blocked my OneDrive ...
Anyway. Someday I tried to remove project folder but I couldn't do it. All of project files were gone except **venv** folder. And yes - I did it twice ...

Folder from the first project that I can't remove is **pycache**  `...\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__pycache__`

Folder from the second project I can't remove is "zh_TW" `...\venv\Lib\site-packages\~phinx\locale\zh_TW`

I think I searched every possible thread that I found. I tired various commends and scripts but I'm still unable to remove them. Could someone advise how to effectively remove remaining venv files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've put virtual environments on OneDrive many times. It works fine for me even if it hammers the network a bit. So I can't see a reason for it to be a problem. Have you tried moving it to another location on the same local drive as OneDrive, or are the files just in the cloud? If the latter, you might be able to remove them using the web interface. Also if your drive is full, you might need to go into the web interface and empty the garbage can.

Comment: @Deepstop I can't remove nor move venv. Removing it via web interface doesn't work as well. Also I'm not running out of free space, so that's not the issue.